# An overlay over an image using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a layer at the top of an image using css. But for some reason the img class is not taking the effect.

Html --

```
<div class="slider">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
</div>
```

Demo  -- https://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/b49a6xkd/

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're applying the background color to the img element, so that background will appear behind the img element. Use a pseudo element to overlay the image instead, and apply the background color to the pseudo element.

```css
.slider {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.slider .wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.slider .wrap:after {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent..Working great.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by using [psuedo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).  You're essentially adding a container to the page, and setting the `background-color` of *that*.

[The fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b49a6xkd/3/).

**The CSS**

```
.slider:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  width:100%;;
  height:400px;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I provided a jsfiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/anp8wgqt/

As mentioned, you need to put some element above the image for the overlay to show. I've done here using a pseudo element, so the same markup as you already have.

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.slider::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 350ms;
}

.slider:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
</div>
```